# Install byobu (screen-profiles) on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, compiling, byobu

I've got mostly Ubuntu servers, but have a need for 2 FreeBSD boxes. On all of the Ubuntu systems I've gotten extremely used to having Byobu on top of GNU Screen. I've been trying to figure out how to get it installed on the FreeBSD boxes from the source tarball, but run into problems at every turn.

I've got everything listed in the README installed (screen, python-newt, and gsed). But I'm still not able to run it properly. It will multiplex the screen just fine, but the bottom line that displays system status and context information just says `Invalid Message (magic 0x00000000000)` and byobu-config says that the snack module is not installed, which I can't seem to find.

Anyone have any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Related: [How to install Python newt or snack in Mac OS X for byobu](http://superuser.com/questions/220386/how-to-install-python-newt-or-snack-in-mac-os-x-for-byobu)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've fixed those problems:

- linked `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash`
- linked `/usr/local/bin/byobu-config` to `/usr/bin/byobu-config`
- linked `/usr/local/bin/byobu-status` to `/usr/bin/byobu-status`
- Reinstalled newt from the ports collection with `WITH_PYTHON=true`

Comment: Hi there!  I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.  This shouldn't be necessary, as long as those are in the $PATH, or you set the --prefix correctly on build.